# accessing properties of nested objects

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, and currently learning it on codecademy.com

Here's the part I don't understand:

```
var friends = {};

friends.bill={};
friends.steve={};

friends.bill={
    firstName:"Bill",
    lastName:"Will",
    number:4164567889,
    address: ['298 Timberbank blvd', 'scarborough', 'ontario']
};

friends.steve={
    firstName:"Steve",
    lastName:"Evan",
    number:4161233333,
    address: ['111 Timberbank blvd', 'scarborough', 'ontario']


for ( var keys in friends){
    console.log(keys);                      // 1. returns 2 objects of friends(bill, steve)
    console.log(keys.firstName);            // 2. why is this wrong?
    console.log(friends[keys].firstName);   // 3. why the properties has to be accessed in this way?
}
```

so far the only thing I can assume is the "for..in" loop returns an array of the objects in "friends". that's why it has to be accessed by using [] notation. Correct me if I was wrong. Thank you

Comment: You can read about any JS syntax construct in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for...in` loop iterates over the **keys** of an Object.

So `keys` is either the string "bill" or "steve", not your friends objects. So `keys.firstName` evaluates to `"bill".firstName` and `"steve".firstName`, which of course is meaningless.

To get the object for the key "bill" in your friends object you can use either `friends.bill` or you can use `friends['bill']`. Bot expressions are equal, but the later allows you to use a variable instead of a string known at compile time. Thus you can use `keys` instead of `'bill'` like this: `friends[keys]`. Then this will actually be your object in friends.